# Is there a way to easily recreate a whole app

Tags: xcode, project

I have a made my first app and I am excited to upload it, but I have recently learnt that a xcode project cannot be uploaded to Google play store, so, as I want to upload it to both areas for maximum downloads, and I do not have a good knowledge for other languages than swift, so I was seeking to learn a way to upload xcode to project to Google play store or to easily convert it.

Comment: xcode is an IDE, not a language. What language did you write your app in?

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you would be either you learn Java/Kotlin and rebuild your app in Android Studio or hire an Android Developer to build it for you since you have no knowledge of other languages than Swift. There's no official tool for IOS to Android App conversion.

Answer (score 1):

No, I have heard of no tooling to bring a native iOS app written Swift app to to other platforms.

You could rewrite your app from scratch.

- [JavaFX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), a GUI framework for use when programming in Java. Can be deployed for each platform (iOS, Android, macOS, Windows, Linux) by bundling a [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

  - A cutting-edge twist is to deploy native code with [ahead-of-time
    compilation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) using [GraalVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM).